# Keras struggles to model simple algebraic function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

My original problem was building a NN for a fairly large dataset, but I ran into an issue where after training the model insistently produces the exact same output for any input so to debug I've moved down to much simpler problems.

I was able to successfully train for basic logical operators - AND, OR, XOR, etc.  So I moved on to trying to model a simple algebraic function y = x^2 + 3x - 7 (I picked this arbitrarily).  The problem is, even for this very simple function, the convergence is incredibly temperamental, takes a huge number of epochs, and often that same "constant output" issue crops up again.

So for example, the code below:

```
 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
 from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# Create a sequential model
    model = Sequential()

    # Define the training data
    X_train = np.array([[-10], [-8], [-6], [-4], [-2], [0], [2], [4], [6], [8], [10]])
    y_train = np.array([[63], [33], [11], [-3], [-9], [-7], [3], [21], [47], [81], [123]])

    # Create a simple neural network model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=6, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(units=12, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(units=6, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    
    # Compile the model
    optimizerClass = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizerClass, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae'])

    # Train the model
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5000, batch_size=1000)

    # Test the trained model
    X_test = np.array([[-9], [-7], [-5], [-3], [-1], [1], [3], [5], [7], [9]])
    y_test = np.array([[47], [21], [3], [-7], [-9], [-3], [11], [33], [63], [101]])
    predictions = model.predict(X_test)
    
    loss, mae = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
    print(f'Overall Test Loss: {loss}, MAE: {mae}')
```

Running this 5 times produces a testing loss between 3.6 and 19.0.  Already it is odd to me that the testing loss would be so variable on such a simple problem, but looking at the individual outputs for each test x, it appears to be producing unique outputs and by and large is fairly accurate.  But then if I add another two layers to the model, like below

```
# Create a sequential model
    model = Sequential()

    # Define the training data
    X_train = np.array([[-10], [-8], [-6], [-4], [-2], [0], [2], [4], [6], [8], [10]])
    y_train = np.array([[63], [33], [11], [-3], [-9], [-7], [3], [21], [47], [81], [123]])

    # Create a simple neural network model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=3, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(units=6, activation='relu')) #extra layer
    model.add(Dense(units=12, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(units=6, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='relu')) #extra layer
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    
    # Compile the model
    optimizerClass = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizerClass, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae'])

    # Train the model
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5000, batch_size=1000)

    # Test the trained model
    X_test = np.array([[-9], [-7], [-5], [-3], [-1], [1], [3], [5], [7], [9]])
    y_test = np.array([[47], [21], [3], [-7], [-9], [-3], [11], [33], [63], [101]])
    predictions = model.predict(X_test)
    
    loss, mae = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
    print(f'Overall Test Loss: {loss}, MAE: {mae}')
```

Now the performance completely breaks.  Running this 5 times produces loss values between 10.8 and 1600 and in every case except the best, vast swathes of the test data produces the same output.

Simplifying the model, with just four layers of 3,6,3,1, produces the same behaviour as the more complicated model - highly variable convergence, with uniform outputs for large sections of the training data.

I've tried playing with batch sizes and learning rates, not to mention a bunch of different network configurations - both simpler and more complex than above - but in general no matter what I do the performance is extremely shaky, and prone to produce useless results.

The fact that this is happening so consistently for such a simple problem makes me suspect that I'm missing something simple in my setup, but for the life of me I can't figure it out

Comment: ReLU is not a good choice for small networks and datasets, as there is a high chance that units "die" and are simply never active. Try using a different activation, e.g. `leaky_relu`.

Comment: Wow, that actually made a huge difference.  Thank you!